# Set URL alias for dynamically created menu links via MenuLinkContent::create

Tags: navigation

I am creating a menu link via the `MenuLinkContent::create` method as follows:

```
MenuLinkContent::create([
  'title' => $createdNodeTitle,
  'link' => ['uri' => "entity:node/$createdNodeId"],
  'menu_name' => 'main',
  'parent' => array_key_first($menu_link),
])->save();
```

Which works fine. I'm looking for a parameter to pass to set a custom URL alias (as possible via UI)

[image]

Any way how this is possible?

Comment: Aliases and menu links are entirely unrelated, so you'll need to give more information about what it is you're doing, and how you've been trying to do it, before we can nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: I think Pathauto had a token for that. Something like menu joint path or so.

Comment: Yes, Pathauto has tokens to do join by menu path.